# bootstrap HTML Select drop down options not aligning in IE 7 Vs IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-7

I hope someone could help me in here , I have been trying to fix this for hours.

I have a bootstrap 3.0 horizontal form , here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="Test" name="first_name" class="form-control other">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="Test" name="last_name" class="form-control other">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
        <select name="gender" class="form-control beta">
            <option value="m">male</option>
            <option value="f">female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CC code for IE 7 & IE 8:

```
.other {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.form-control {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

select {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

label {
    color: #4F959A;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have a screen shot to show in Both IE 7 & IE8

IE7: [image]

IE8:  [image]

I would like the IE 7 to look close to how the iE 8 looks , even you can see that I have an issue with aligning the text in the Select drop down , its not centered ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, as far I know is css not really supported in IE7 and IE7 is verry old (I do not support IE7 anymore). But maybe you have a chance positioning the OPTION instead of the SELECT.

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap v3 only supports IE8+. You perhaps might try https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7 or similar.

Comment: are you from the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use CSS hacks in this case.  Go [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/) for a large list of them.

If I want to just target IE8 and below I do something like below:

```
.element {
  color: blue\9;
}
```

If it's IE7 and below I do the following:

```
.element {
  *color: blue;
}
```

In your case it looks like you need to play around with the `select` element.  You could maybe do a `margin-left: -10px` or position it relatively and do a `right` or `left`:

```
.select {
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
}
```